# Matlab GPU arrayfun shared variable

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, shared-memory, gpgpu

I am using [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) *GPU computing* with function `arrayfun` and a `gpuArray` object to do element-wise function on elements of the `gpuArray` variable on my function:

```
[ output ] = MyFunc( element, SharedMatrix )
//
// Process element with Shared Matrix
//
end
```

and my code is like so:

```
SharedMatrix = magic(5000); %Large Memory Object
SharedMatrix = gpuArray(SharedMatrix);
elements = magic(5);
gpuElements = gpuArray(elements );
//Error on next line, SharedMatrix object must be a scaler.
result = arrayfun(@MyFunc,gpuElements,SharedMatrix);
```

I've heard that global variables can't be used in *GPU computing*.

Is there a way to do so with `arrayfun` ?

Comment: You need to convert SharedMatrix to gpuArray as well.

Comment: Even if I did, It process it element by element not as a whole matrix.
And it needs to be with the same dimensionality as *gpuElements* matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrayfun` currently require all inputs to be compatible sizes (or scalars), and the processing is done in an elementwise manner.

Also, `Parallel Computing Toolbox` in Matlab don't support `Global Variables`, So it can't be done using the `Parallel Computing Toolbox`.

Answer (score 4):

Using recent versions of Parallel Computing Toolbox, this can be done for example by using a nested function in conjunction with `arrayfun`, like so:

```
function result = gpueg()

largeArray = gpuArray.rand(5000);

smallArray = magic(5);

    function out = myNestedFcn(in)
    % nested function accesses 'smallArray'    
        element = ceil(in * 25);
        out = smallArray(element);
    end

result = arrayfun(@myNestedFcn, largeArray);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can use a [handle class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html):

```
classdef VarByRefContainer < handle
    properties
        val = [];
    end
end

handle = VarByRefContainer;
handle.val = SharedMatrix;
cellfun(@myfun, {handle, handle, handle});
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343209/can-i-share-memory-between-cellfun-threads-on-gpu).