# Can I share memory between cellfun threads on GPU?

Tags: matlab, gpu

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607558/matlab-gpu-arrayfun-shared-variable), I'm trying to share a matrix between threads of cellfun running on a GPU.

As GPU execution doesn't support globals, I was thinking I could define an array of handle class objects with a reference to the shared matrix, so a handle will be passed to each cellfun instance.

```
classdef VarByRefContainer < handle
    properties
        val = [];
    end
end

handle = VarByRefContainer;
handle.val = SharedMatrix;
cellfun(@myfun, {handle, handle, handle});
```

Matlab seems to accept this, but there remain a couple of questions:

1. Is this safe? I.e. if I assign a value to elements [1,3,5] and [2,4] in parallel, is there a possibility that the assignments clash?
2. Is this efficient? I.e. the handler class might be stored on the host, and referencing the memory on the GPU might be a time consuming operation. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post the same answer here as to the other question - you can share data using up-level variables and nested functions:

```
function result = gpueg()

largeArray = gpuArray.rand(5000);

smallArray = magic(5);

    function out = myNestedFcn(in)
    element = ceil(in * 25);
    out = smallArray(element);
    end

result = arrayfun(@myNestedFcn, largeArray);

end
```

Comment: It's safe because you cannot modify the up-level variables. It's hard to say in general whether it's efficient - depends on how much data you're accessing in this way.

Comment: The point is that I need to modify the up-level variable... I just tried this in Matlab and it seems to work - it doesn't prevent me from changing the up-level variable. Tested on CPU, not yet on GPU.

Comment: The GPU does not let you modify the up-level variable because that would be a race condition. If you need this sort of 'communication' between threads, it's best if you can to use an established communication pattern (such as a reduction (e.g. SUM) or a scan (e.g. CUMSUM)).

Comment: I've tested this and it seems to work... As for race conditions, I'm taking care of writing to separate indices at each thread. Should I still be worried?